# Jenkins Choice Parameter delete after job done

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I Have simple Jenkins job

List of available subnets user can use , after he choose subnet and run the job --> he can not use the
same subnet again for the next time he will run the job

[image]

Can you help me to establish it? is it somthing need to write in code ? or there is an build-in option

Comment: so you want to look at build history for a user and build that list for them on the next build. that new list will exclude previously selected  items by that user?
Leaving this info in the build date seems like a bad idea. you might want to use a small DB to build this list and keep track of who submitted what. and build the from from that data.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add this login to the code the job run so it will check if subnet already used via code and respond to the user.
Alternatively, use https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/ to use groovy to check for existing subnets and populate parameter accordingly